# I'm getting some errors when I try to implement a generic datatype to my class

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to search, but I can't quite find the answer to my problem. I feel like I've implemented my generic datatype correctly but I'm still getting an error.

I'm doing an exercise where I'm given constructors/methods and variables (so I can't change the variable inputs for instance), and now I have to write the constructors/methods to make them work. The program creates an array (objects) that can grow by adding elements to it, and the comments above each method in the code explains what they do.

When I try to create the arrays in my two constructors, I get the error "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer" for the empty array and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from T[] to int".

In my "add" method I get the error "Cannot invoke add(int, T) on the array type T[]" and finally in my "toArray" method I get the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to T[]".

The common theme seems to be that I haven't implemented the generic datatype correctly, but no matter how many times I try to search for similar questions, I can't see how what I've done have been different.

When searching, I see many people say that an array can't "grow" and to instead use an ArrayList, however there has to be a way to solve this with just an array, otherwise you can't solve this exercise.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GrowingArray<T> {
    private Object[] objects;
    private int pointer;

    //empty array
    public GrowingArray() {
        objects = new Object[];
    }

    //array that contains ds
    public GrowingArray(T[] ds) {
        objects = new Object[ds];
    }   

    // add element e and return true
    public boolean add(T e) {
        pointer = 0;
        objects.add(pointer++, e);
        return true;
    }

    // return true if value d is found in the array
    public boolean contains(T d) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= objects.length; i++) {
            if(objects[i] == d) {
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // return the element on index i
    public T get(int index) {
        int i = index;
        return objects[i];
    }

    // return first index containing d, if not found return -1
    public int indexOf(T d) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= objects.length; i++) {
              if(d == objects[i]) {
                  return i;
              }
          }
          return -1;
    }

    // return last index containing d, if not found return -1
    public int lastIndexOf(T d) {
        for(int i = objects.length; i >= 0; i--) {
              if(d == objects[i]) {
                  return i;
              }
          }
          return -1;
    }

    // return length of array
    public int size() {
        return objects.length;
    }

    // return a trimmed version of the array
    public T[] toArray() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(objects, objects.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: @John Kugelman: I updated the changes and also noticed I had made a mistake by writing `private T[] objects;` instead of `private Object[] objects;`. I have also updated the error messages now, which still seems to be in the same places, although slightly different.

Comment: There is not a single problem in the code you posted.  There are a great many errors.  It does not appear that you know how to instantiate an array, for example.  In Java, arrays have a fixed and unchangeable size; therefore "growing" a collection must be done by allocating a new, larger array, and then copying the contents of the old array to the new one.  Also, invoking the `add` method on an `Object[]` array makes no sense ... Object arrays have no add method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> objects = new Object[];
> ```
>
> "Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer"

You need to pass a size. Empty brackets don't work.

```
objects = new Object[someInitialSize];
```

---

> ```
> objects = new Object[ds];
> ```
>
> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from T[] to int"

To copy an array use `Arrays.copyOf`:

```
objects = Arrays.copyOf(ds, ds.length);
```